# To create type Matrix, which incapsulates two-dimensional array-matrix block of real (double) type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have another task. Since I did not study at a technical university and I remember this topic only a little from school problems, it is hard for me to complete the task. Please do not judge me harshly.

The task looks like this:
Task
To create type Matrix, which incapsulates two-dimensional array-matrix
block of real (double) type.
Matrix is the cover for two-dimensional array of real values, storing matrix
values with operations of matrix addition, deduction and multiplication.
Real type values (double) can be in matrix, specifying during creation, the
number of array rows and columns, which will store these values. After
creation, the number of rows and columns are not changed. Values to matrix
elements can be set while creating matrix, and later with the help of indexer.
Matrix can provide information regarding the number of array rows and
columns, receive array elements in form of two-dimensional standard array,
add, deduct and multiply matrixes compatible by size. If a user is trying to
perform operations with matrix of incompatible sizes – user type exceptions
MatrixException are thrown from operations. Other matrix methods also
throw exceptions, if a user applies them incorrectly (conveys incorrect
parameters into constructor, in indexer – non-existing index and so on).
Implementation of the following functionality is required in Matrix class:
• Creating of empty matrix with predetermined number of rows and
columns (all values in matrix equal 0).
• Creating of matrix based on existing two-dimensional array.
• Receiving of number of matrix rows and columns.
• Receiving of standard two-dimensional array out of matrix.
• Access to recording and reading of elements via predetermined correct
index (indexer).
• Method of matrixes addition.
• Method of matrixes deduction.
• Method of matrixes multiplication.
• Raise exceptions specified in xml-comments to class methods.

Here is the code I was able to write that passes the tests:

```
using System;

namespace MatrixLibrary
{
    class MatrixException : Exception
    {
        public int Rows { get; }
        public int Columns { get; }

        public override string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return "incorrect quantity of rows/columns";
            }
        }
        public MatrixException(int rows, int columns)
        {
            this.Rows = rows;
            this.Columns = columns;
        }

    }
    // TODO: Create custom exception "MatrixException"

    public class Matrix : ICloneable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Number of rows.
        /// </summary>
        public int Rows
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of columns.
        /// </summary>
        public int Columns
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an array of floating-point values that represents the elements of this Matrix.
        /// </summary>
        public double[,] Array
        {
            get; set;
          
          
            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Matrix"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rows"></param>
        /// <param name="columns"></param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"></exception>
        public Matrix(int rows, int columns)
        {
            Rows = rows;
            Columns = columns;
            Array = new double[Rows, Columns];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Matrix"/> class with the specified elements.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="array">An array of floating-point values that represents the elements of this Matrix.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        public Matrix(double[,] array)
        {
            this.Rows = array.GetLength(0);
            this.Columns = array.GetLength(1);
            this.Array = array;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows instances of a Matrix to be indexed just like arrays.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="row"></param>
        /// <param name="column"></param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
        public double this[int row, int column]
        {
            get
            {

                return this.Array[row, column];
            }
            set
            {

                this.Array[row, column] = value;
            }
        }
```

But what I can't write correctly:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Creates a deep copy of this Matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A deep copy of the current object.</returns>
        public object Clone()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds two matrices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix1"></param>
        /// <param name="matrix2"></param>
        /// <returns>New <see cref="Matrix"/> object which is sum of two matrices.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public static Matrix operator +(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Subtracts two matrices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix1"></param>
        /// <param name="matrix2"></param>
        /// <returns>New <see cref="Matrix"/> object which is subtraction of two matrices</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public static Matrix operator -(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Multiplies two matrices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix1"></param>
        /// <param name="matrix2"></param>
        /// <returns>New <see cref="Matrix"/> object which is multiplication of two matrices.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public static Matrix operator *(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds <see cref="Matrix"/> to the current matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix"><see cref="Matrix"/> for adding.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public Matrix Add(Matrix matrix)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subtracts <see cref="Matrix"/> from the current matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix"><see cref="Matrix"/> for subtracting.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public Matrix Subtract(Matrix matrix)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Multiplies <see cref="Matrix"/> on the current matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix"><see cref="Matrix"/> for multiplying.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public Matrix Multiply(Matrix matrix)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tests if <see cref="Matrix"/> is identical to this Matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Object to compare with. (Can be null)</param>
        /// <returns>True if matrices are equal, false if are not equal.</returns>
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() => base.GetHashCode();
    }
```

I would be grateful for help

Comment: Actually, before you create the table or matrix, the real question is where did the data come from in the first place? Since say if the data comes from say a database, then we can use a datatable and not have to create the table like structure to hold this data - since we have a ready made built in structure called a datatable.  So often this is much like a chicken and a egg problem. But a big part of this process would be where did the numbers and values come from, where are they stored, and if they are stored in say a database, then we could and likely should use a datatable for this.

Comment: So you can certainlly create or build up some kind of table or matrix in code, but knowning and thinking about where the information will come from in the first place should be the starting point here. As noted, if the data comes from some data source, then we can in one operation pull that data into that data table. Once done, then there is a set of rich controls say like a data grid that can then automatic render that table for display on a web page. So, where is the data to come from should be part of this question. If it comes from a data source then fill a datatable from that source.

Comment: The fact of the matter is that there is no database, as well as the data itself. There is no way to upload data. All I have is the skeleton file above and a task to it.

Comment: This detail would darn near allow you to save world poverty and save truckloads of code. So it was at least worth a try to ask in regards to saving suffering and darn near as noted world poverty in the amount of work you will be faced with. however, since as you noted the data is not coming from a database, then you have to get that pot of coffee out and just code though this as you are doing now. however, even in this case using a data table for your structure would give you a matrix like structure and with a lot less code.  You just create a table with columns and rows and reference that.